# Scale- and Rotation Invariant Checkerboard Pattern Detection for Video Stabilization on MATLAB [2x2 Pattern is needed]

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching, detection, pattern-recognition, template-matching

**Summary:** My Objective is to gather the pixels of checkerboard patterns (originally identical but on the frame different looking checkerboard patterns, because of the perspective) distributed on various positions of a video set and use these pixel coordinates to stabilise the video.

MATLAB's own function detectCheckerboardPoints doesn't work for patterns smaller than 4x4. And what I need is **2x2 checkerboard pattern detection** on a video to detect the pattern locations and compare the positions of these patterns with each other for a **video stabilization process**.

Here is my own code which **doesn't work properly** and really **slow**. I need a **faster and a more accurate** one. I tried to check if the contrast difference is high enough between two pixels while moving to the right, downwards, to the left and upwards. If all of them gives a high contrast value on a 9 unit square I save the coordinates of these pixels.

(I tried to get a recognition over the **Fourier Transformation** as well, it worked way faster than mine, but it was **not accurate enough**, it couldn't find the checkerboard patterns distributed on the image, probably because of the variation of the pattern size.)

Thanks in advance...

```
clc; close all; clear all;

I_rgb = imread('frame1.jpg');
[rows cols numberOfColorBands] =size(I_rgb);
I_gray=rgb2gray(I_rgb);
% x=i y=j
figure; imshow(I_rgb); hold on;
i=1;
x=1;
y=1;
color_change=0;
h=1;
checkers_dots=0;
array=[0 0];

for i=1:rows-1
    for j=1:(cols-1)
        for m=j:(j+9)                      
            g=2222;
            x(i,j)=I_gray(i,j);
            x(i,j+1)=I_gray(i,j+1);
            if abs(x(i,j+1)-x(i,j))>=120 
            color_change=color_change+1;
            d=0; % contrast high enough while moving to the right

            end
        end    

        for n=(i+9):-1:i
            e=2222;
            x(i,j)=I_gray(i,j);
            x(i+1,j)=I_gray(i+1,j);
            if abs(x(i,j+1)-x(i,j))>=120 
            color_change=color_change+1;
            e=0; %contrast high enough while moving downwards   
            end    
        end
        for p=(j+9):-1:1
            f=2222;
            x(i,j)=I_gray(i,j);
            x(i,j+1)=I_gray(i,j+1);
            if abs(x(i,j+1)-x(i,j))>=120 
            color_change=color_change+1;
            f=0; %contrast high enough while moving to the left
            end    
        end
        for r=i:(i+9)
            g=2222;
            x(i,j)=I_gray(i,j);
            x(i+1,j)=I_gray(i+1,j);
            if abs(x(i,j+1)-x(i,j))>=120 
            color_change=color_change+1;
            g=0;  %contrast high enough while moving upwards   
            end

        end

        if (g==0 && f==0 && e==0 && d==0)    
%if all conditions apply get the pixel           
            plot(j, i, 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 7, 'LineWidth', 5);
                hold on;
                checkers_dots=checkers_dots+1;

        array(h,1)= j;
        array(h,2) = i;
        h=h+1;



    end
    end    
end
        display(color_change, 'Vertical color switching points')
        display(checkers_dots, 'Checkers Pattern Dots')
%------------%
% x=i y=j
%------------%
```

Comment: Do you have a sample image that you used so we can reconstruct your problem? It'll also help in giving an answer as the code will be tailored towards your specific data.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to send the video set, but I can describe it. I have a 13 minutes video taken by a quadcopter with a camera over a traffic crossroads. (Various vehicles are passing by, and the bushes on the sides of the road swing a little) During the shooting copter swings a little either and rotates a few angles due to the wind blowing and then comes back to almost the same position. The frames don't change much but the movement causes the pattern recognition to be scale and rotation invariant.